# how to create function in PHP for Timestamp

Tags: php, function

I am converting time of server like this :

```
$olddate = $rowHomeTop["DandTStory"];
$now = time();
$old = strtotime( $olddate);
$diff =  $now-$old;
$old = new DateTime($olddate);
$old = $old->format('d M Y');
$nmeng = array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov', 'Dec');
$nmtur = array('جنوری','فروری','مارچ','اپریل','مئ','جون','جولائی','اگست','ستمبر','اکتوبر','نومبر','دسمبر');
$dt = str_ireplace($nmeng, $nmtur, $old);
    if ($diff /60 <1)
    {
    echo intval($diff%60)." سیکنڈ پہلے";
    }
    else if (intval($diff/60) == 1) 
    {
    echo "ایک منٹ پہلے";
    }
    else if ($diff / 60 < 60)
    {
    echo intval($diff/60)." منٹ پہلے";
    }
    else if (intval($diff / 3600) == 1)
    {
    echo "ایک گھنٹہ ".intval($diff/60%60)." منٹ پہلے";
    }
    else if ($diff / 3600 <24)
    {
    echo intval($diff/3600) . " گھنٹے " .intval($diff/60%60)." منٹ پہلے ";
    }
    else
    {
    echo $dt;
    }
```

It is very difficult to use this code where I want to show time.
I want that just I type `<?php echo time($rowHomeTop["DandTStory"]) ?>` and show time instead of pasting that long code.

Comment: do you want to know how to create function in php?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function customTime($olddate)
{
    $now = time();
    $old = strtotime( $olddate);
    $diff =  $now-$old;
    $old = new DateTime($olddate);
    $old = $old->format('d M Y');
    $nmeng = array('Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov', 'Dec');
    $nmtur = array('جنوری','فروری','مارچ','اپریل','مئ','جون','جولائی','اگست','ستمبر','اکتوبر','نومبر','دسمبر');
    $dt = str_ireplace($nmeng, $nmtur, $old);
        if ($diff /60 <1)
        {
        return intval($diff%60)." سیکنڈ پہلے";
        }
        else if (intval($diff/60) == 1) 
        {
        return "ایک منٹ پہلے";
        }
        else if ($diff / 60 < 60)
        {
        return intval($diff/60)." منٹ پہلے";
        }
        else if (intval($diff / 3600) == 1)
        {
        return "ایک گھنٹہ ".intval($diff/60%60)." منٹ پہلے";
        }
        else if ($diff / 3600 <24)
        {
        return intval($diff/3600) . " گھنٹے " .intval($diff/60%60)." منٹ پہلے ";
        }
        else
        {
        return $dt;
        }
}
```

after that

```
echo customTime($rowHomeTop["DandTStory"]);
```

Comment: The function already `echo`s so you either just want `time($rowHomeTop["DandTStory"]);` or you change the `echo`s in the function to `return`s.

Comment: Amazing that is working now, but my final Question is how can I keep this code in one page then how can I include that php page in all pages?

Comment: I want I just add that page and call that function